# 2D rendering color problems

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new in 2D programming and right now I'm trying to make a 2D game with some clouds that are scrolled in the bottom of the screen. It was easy to make that happen but I don't know why, the clouds are put in a black rectangle. Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

http://gyazo.com/b16c9f3242c1ec62244f20bd1b61bba3

Code here:

```
public class Scrollable {

    protected Vector2 position;
    protected Vector2 velocity;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected boolean isScrolledDown;

    public Scrollable(float x, float y, int width, int height, float scrollSpeed) {
        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        velocity = new Vector2(0, scrollSpeed);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        isScrolledDown = false;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));

        if (position.y + height  < 0) {
            isScrolledDown = true;
        }
    }

    public void reset(float newY) {
        position.y = newY;
        isScrolledDown = false;
    }

    public boolean isScrolledDown() {
        return isScrolledDown;
    }

    public float getTailY() {
        return position.y + height;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return position.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return position.y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

}



public class ScrollHandler {

    private Clouds cloud1, cloud2, cloud3;
    public static final int SCROLL_SPEED = -59;

    public ScrollHandler(float yPos) {

        cloud1= new Clouds(80, 0, 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);
        cloud2 = new Clouds(50 , cloud1.getTailY(), 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);
        cloud3 = new Clouds(10, cloud2.getTailY(), 30, 80, SCROLL_SPEED);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {

        cloud1.update(delta);
        cloud2.update(delta);
        cloud3.update(delta);


         if (cloud1.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud1.reset(cloud3.getTailY());

         } else if (cloud2.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud2.reset(cloud1.getTailY());

         } else if (cloud3.isScrolledDown()) {
            cloud3.reset(cloud2.getTailY());
         }

}


    public Clouds getCloud1() {
        return cloud1;
    }

    public Clouds getCloud2() {
        return cloud2;
    }

    public Clouds getCloud3() {
        return cloud3;
    }

}



public class GameRenderer {

    private GameWorld myWorld;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    private SpriteBatch batcher;

    private int midPointY;
    private int gameHeight;

    // Game Objects
    private Margarine marg;
    private ScrollHandler scroller;
    private Clouds cloud1, cloud2, cloud3;

    // Game Assets
    private TextureRegion cloud;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world, int gameHeight, int midPointY) {
        myWorld = world;

        this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
        this.midPointY = midPointY;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, 136, gameHeight);

        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        // Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
        initGameObjects();
        initAssets();
    }

    private void initGameObjects() {
        marg = myWorld.getMargarine();
        scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
        cloud1 = scroller.getCloud1();
        cloud2 = scroller.getCloud2();
        cloud3 = scroller.getCloud3();

    }

    private void initAssets() {

        cloud = AssetLoader.cloud;
    }

    public void render(float runTime) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

        // Draw Background color

        shapeRenderer.setColor(102 / 255.0f, 102 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, 136, midPointY + 66);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, midPointY + 66, 136, 11);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, midPointY + 77, 136, 52);

        shapeRenderer.end();

        batcher.begin();
        batcher.disableBlending();


        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud1.getX(), cloud1.getY(), cloud1.getWidth(),
                cloud1.getHeight());

        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud2.getX(), cloud2.getY(), cloud2.getWidth(),
                cloud2.getHeight());

        batcher.draw(cloud, cloud3.getX(), cloud3.getY(), cloud3.getWidth(),
                cloud3.getHeight());

        batcher.draw(AssetLoader.marg, marg.getX(), marg.getY(),
                marg.getWidth(), marg.getHeight());

        batcher.end();

    }

}
```

Comment: Just curious...why are you drawing three rectangles stacked on top of each other instead of just one? And by the way, if you simply want to fill the whole background with a solid color, you can put the color into the `glClearColor` line and skip drawing the rectangles. Otherwise, you're wasting a lot of GPU cycles.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm just following some tutorials. Didn't notice the part with glClearColor, thanks a lot for that.

Comment: thanks for clearing that point out... (was just a lucky guess...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black rectangles are because you called `disableBlending()` on the sprite batch. Blending is what allows a sprite to have transparency.